# Why does my Com Ocx not catch Key Presses in IE7

Tags: com, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, compatibility, ocx

We have a COM OCX that catches various keypresses to IE when it's loaded into a web page.  This OCX works well in IE6, however does not catch any keypresses in IE7.

- It does load in IE7, generate other events (which are caught by Javascript).
- It throws no errors.
- I've run the [Microsoft Application Compatability Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=24DA89E9-B581-47B0-B45E-492DD6DA2971&displaylang=en) as it's running in IE7 and get no entries whatsoever.
- The control does not require focus to work in IE6.  It works by getting an OS Level keyhook to the process.
- The control correctly gets the IE7 PID, and reports that it is set.
- The control is build around [Desaware's Spyworks](http://www.desaware.com/products/universalcom/spyworks/index.aspx).
- Both tests (IE6 and IE7) where tested on Windows XP computers with the same account.

I've read every post on IE7 Compatability Issues I can find, and none reference keypresses.  What could possibly be preventing this from working.

Answer (score 1):

The control need to be in focus in order to catch key presses, try tabing to the control and then pressing the clicks.

If you want to catch the clicks on the entire page you can install a JavaScript handler that will route the event to the OCX.

Comment: Please see my edit.  Sorry my original question was not clear enough.